# Swift 3 : Warning "Unused result of call" when overriding BecomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, swift3

In a `UIView` subclass, I'm override `BecomeFirstResponder` (which returns a `Bool`.

```
class MyViewSubclass:UIView {
 ...
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        // some stuff
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
 ...
}
```

When calling this method on a object of the subclass, I get a warning `Result of call to 'becomeFirstResponder()' is Unused`.

This message doesn't not happened when I don't override `becomeFirstResponder`.

I know that with Swift 3 the behaviour of methods returning results has evolved (see `@discardableResult` on [SE-0047](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md)) but I would expect an override to have the same behaviour as its super method.

Am I wrong for thinking that or is it maybe a compiler bug ?

**Edit**: 
FYI, [I filed a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2198) for this.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. It could of course be intentional since your implementation might be completely different, but seems odd.

Comment: i have the some problem. and yes, I think it's a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug [has been solved](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3377) in the lastest Swift version.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is bug. If you have override a function, then it could totally be possible that the return value now cannot be ignored. I would simply add `@discardableResult` if that's what you want:

```
@discardableResult override open func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    // some stuff
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be the right way, even tho im not expert on swift, but from Objective-C

```
class MyViewSubclass:UIView {
 ...
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        // some stuff
        super.becomeFirstResponder()
     return true
    }
 ...
}
```